# Why is the list of files for a range of commits different from the aggregation of the lists of files per commit in the same range?

Tags: git

Please, observe:

```
C:\xyz\tip [master ≡]> git log --format="%h" b00bf1df0..81317ea59
81317ea59
b7d9617fc
C:\xyz\tip [master ≡]> $files1 = git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r b7d9617fc
C:\xyz\tip [master ≡]> $files2 = git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r 81317ea59
C:\xyz\tip [master ≡]> $files3 = git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r b00bf1df0..81317ea59
C:\xyz\tip [master ≡]> $files1.Length
17
C:\xyz\tip [master ≡]> $files2.Length
0
C:\xyz\tip [master ≡]> $files3.Length
43
C:\xyz\tip [master ≡]>
```

So, the range of commits `b00bf1df0..81317ea59` returns just two commits - `81317ea59` and `b7d9617fc`

Next I am taking the lists of files in these two commits separately and then from the whole range as one.

1. The first commit in the range (`b7d9617fc`) yields 17 files (`files1.Length`)
2. The second commit in the range (`81317ea59`) yields 0 files (`files2.Length`), which is OK because it is a **merge** commit.
3. But when I am taking the files in the commit range that produces the same 2 commits, i.e. `b00bf1df0..81317ea59` it is suddenly 43 files (`files3.Length`). Note, that all the files in `files1` are included in `files3`, but there are quite a lot more in `files3`.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

With commit `81317ea59` being a merge, `git diff-tree 81317ea59` (with the additional options) does indeed show no files because it does nothing, but `git diff-tree b00bf1df0..81317ea59` means `git diff-tree b00bf1df0 81317ea59`, which compares the tree found by:

```
git rev-parse b00bf1df0^{tree}
```

with that of:

```
git rev-parse 81317ea59^{tree}
```

which is exactly two specific trees, so Git compares them.

Arguments like `b00bf1df0..81317ea59` mean commit *ranges* to *some* Git commands (like `git log`), but *never* mean commit ranges to any `git diff` command, because Git's diff can't deal with ranges.

It would be instructive to run `git diff-tree -m -r 81317ea59` or (and I think better) `git show -m 81317ea59`.  The `-m` flag makes Git show you the actual diff from the merge to each of its parents, separately.  It's important to omit the `--no-commit-id` option here so that you can see the transition from one parent to the next, when using `git diff-tree`.

## Long

These diffs don't do what you think they do.

(I'm not sure what shell you're using, so I will express these without the variable assignments.)

#### The setup

Let's start with [the `git diff-tree` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html), which has this to say about arguments:

> > *git diff-tree* [`--stdin`] [`-m`] [`-s`] [`-v`] [`--no-commit-id`] [`--pretty`]
> >      [`-t`] [`-r`] [`-c` | `--cc`] [`--root`] [`<common diff options>`]
> >      `<tree-ish>` [`<tree-ish>`] [`<path>...`]

The variant you run the first two times has just one `<tree>` argument, so we read on to find:

> > #### DESCRIPTION
> >
> > Compares the content and mode of the blobs found via two tree objects.
> >
> > If there is only one <tree-ish> given, the commit is compared with its parents (see --stdin below).
> >
> > Note that *git diff-tree* can use the tree encapsulated in a commit object.

The `--name-only` and `-r` options are described later as restricting the output to the names of files found to be different, and to recurse into sub-trees.  The documentation fails to explain the **extremely important** fact that `b00bf1df0..81317ea59` is interpreted *as if* you wrote `b00bf1df0 81317ea59`, i.e., this is the *two*-tree form of `git diff-tree`.

The documentation *does* explain, poorly, a third item that is also crucial, but does so buried deep within the manual page.  Let's take a look at these last two options:

> > `-c`
> >
> > This flag changes the way a merge commit is displayed (which means it is useful only when the command is given one <tree-ish>, or `--stdin`). It shows the differences from each of the parents to the merge result simultaneously instead of showing pairwise diff between a parent and the result one at a time (which is what the `-m` option does). Furthermore, it lists only files which were modified from all parents.
> >
> > `--cc`
> >
> > This flag changes the way a merge commit patch is displayed, in a similar way to the `-c` option. It implies the `-c` and `-p` options and further compresses the patch output by omitting uninteresting hunks whose the contents in the parents have only two variants and the merge result picks one of them without modification. When all hunks are uninteresting, the commit itself and the commit log message is not shown, just like in any other "empty diff" case.

This fails to mention that with no options, the default for looking at a *merge* commit, when given a single `tree-ish` argument that is actually a commit ID, is to *ignore the commit entirely*.  This is the default diff-behavior for both `git log` and `git diff-tree`, though `git log` will at least print the log message first.

(This "do nothing when we encounter a merge commit" behavior is also true for `git diff --raw`, but not for plain `git diff`, nor for `git show`; these default to `-c` style combined diffs.  From the documentation, `git diff-files` also defaults to not showing merges, although I'm not sure under what circumstances `git diff-files` would even *see* a merge since it compares index vs work-tree.  It is true that the index can be *unmerged*, which diff handles similarly to merges: the three merge slots for each file provide base and branch-tip versions.  Perhaps this is what the documentation is alluding to here.)

#### The diffs

You mention that commit `81317ea59` is a merge (has at least two parents).  Presumably commit `b7d9617fc` is not a merge, and `b00bf1df0` is yet another commit that may or may not be a merge—it does not matter given the way the hash ID is used.

The first `git diff-tree` command is:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r b7d9617fc
```

This looks at a non-merge, so Git finds the (single, only) parent of `b7d9617fc` and compares those two trees, a la:

```
git diff --name-only b7d9617fc^ b7d9617fc
```

which lists some files.

The second command is:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r 81317ea59
```

Commit `81317ea59` is a merge, so this prints nothing at all.

The third command is:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r b00bf1df0..81317ea59
```

which gives two `<tree-ish>` arguments and therefore:

> > Compares the content and mode of the blobs found via two tree objects.

In other words, it does the same as:

```
git diff --name-only b00bf1df0 81317ea59
```

(which, not coincidentally, can also use the two-dot notation, and also simply compares those two specific commits).

Comment: I have read the documentation again, but my poor brain was burned by it. Would you mind looking at https://stackoverflow.com/q/53525603/80002 ?