# How to list all the files changed in the Pull Request being currently validated (in VSTS)?

Tags: git

I have a PR validation build that I want to list all the files changed in the PR along with the status.

The sources are synced on each build.
So, before the PR changes are merged, the source is at revision `A` (typically `origin/master`).
Let me designate PR merge commit as `B`.

My current implementation calls `git diff-tree --name-status -r -M A..B`, but as [Why is the list of files for a range of commits different from the aggregation of the lists of files per commit in the same range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53512519/why-is-the-list-of-files-for-a-range-of-commits-different-from-the-aggregation-o) shows this is incorrect.

So, what is the correct way? Note, that the Pull Request may contain several commits with at least one merge commit - `B`. But there could be more merge commits there.

I am pretty sure there is a pure Git way to do it and there is no need to execute Restful API against the TFS server to inspect the Pull Request object.

**EDIT 1**

Let `A = b00bf1df0` and `B = 81317ea59`.

Given (I am using Powershell):

```
C:\Dayforce\tip [master ≡]> git log --format="%h" b00bf1df0..81317ea59
81317ea59
b7d9617fc
C:\Dayforce\tip [master ≡]>
```

And indeed, the PR in question has one commit - `b7d9617fc` with `81317ea59` being the PR merge commit (i.e. it is `B`)

As my other post shows, `git diff-tree --name-status -r -M b00bf1df0..81317ea59` is incorrect.

I believe using `...` is incorrect too, indeed: `git diff-tree --name-status -r -M b00bf1df0...81317ea59` returns nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental problem is that the question is ill-formed:

> ... list all the files changed in the PR along with the status

A pull request is, in effect, a request of the form: *Please change branch name `B` so that instead of pointing to whatever commit it points to at the time you get around to changing it, it points to commit `C` instead.  Do this however you like, but perhaps by making **your own** merge commit.*  This pull-request thing may or may not—it's hard to say since pull requests are not part of Git itself, but rather add-ons provided by various web services, and each web-service can implement this however *they* like—include information of the form: *And by the way, when I asked you to change the value of name `B` to hash ID `C`, the value **was** hash ID `O`.*

Let's assume for the moment that it provides all three items: a branch name *`B`*, an old commit hash ID *`O`*, and a requested commit hash ID *`C`*.  Let's also state that *`B`*'s actual hash value is currently *`A`*.  Maybe *`A`* = *`O`*, and maybe not.  (If *`O`* is not included in the pull request, that's not really fatal, but it will be up to you to find a suitable substitute, and define how it all works and so on.)

#### What to know about commits

Now, the first thing about a commit hash ID is that it designates *one particular commit*, and each commit is a *complete snapshot of all files*.  It's not a set of changes at all!  It's just a state, like declaring that the temperature outside today is 68˚F (20˚C).  By itself, this tells you nothing about what it was yesterday or last week.  To turn a *state* into a *change*, you must pick some other state to compare it to.  If it was 77˚F (25˚C) yesterday, the *change* is 9˚F (5˚C).

We do the same thing with commits in Git: we pick one state—such as *`C`*—and compare it to some previous state.  But we just said that the *actual* previous state is *`A`*, while the *recorded* previous state is *`O`*.  If you compare *`C`* vs *`O`*, you'll get a different answer than if you compare *`C`* vs *`A`*, unless of course *`A`* = *`O`*.

But that's not the only thing about a commit.  Each commit also records zero or more *parent* commit hash IDs—usually exactly 1, and the next most common is 2 for merge commits.  (Zero parents means the commit is a *root* commit; usually there's just one of these per repository, for the very first commit.  Three or more is an *octopus merge*.)  The parents of *`C`* are each commits in their own right, which also have parents, and so on.  Taking the parents into account, what we really have could be something like this:

```
...--D--E--F--O--A   <-- B
         \     \
          G--H--C   <-- (pull requested at C)
```

Or, it could be simpler:

```
...--D--E--F--A   <-- B
               \
                G--C   <-- (pull requested at C)
```

where `A` and `O` are the same commit.  Or it could even be a request to remove some commit(s), though some web services would not allow this, or would take no action if you use their "accept request" interface(s), but let's just draw it:

```
...--C--O--A   <-- B
```

(with the request amounting to *please "rewind" B so that commits `A` and `O` vanish*).

#### What if another merge is called-for?

Let's look at this graph again:

```
...--D--E--F--O--A   <-- B
         \     \
          G--H--C   <-- (pull requested at C)
```

On GitHub, at least, if you use the default kind of "merge pull request", what GitHub will do is add a *new* commit—let's call it `M`—whose *snapshot* is formed by running a *new* `git merge` (on GitHub),<sup>1</sup> even though `C` itself is a merge commit.  The snapshot in `M` will be that produced by combining changes.  The end product will be:

```
...--D--E--F--O--A--M   <-- B
         \     \ __/
          G--H--C
```

But GitHub also offers two other ways to accept this pull request, each of which does something different.  If commits `G`, `H`, and `C` are not already in *your* repository, the *rebase and merge* option produces instead this graph:

```
...--D--E--F--O--A--G'-H'   <-- B
```

while the *squash and merge* option produces:

```
...--D--E--F--O--A--S   <-- B
```

where `S` has the *contents* that `M` would have, if GitHub had made `M`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The way GitHub makes a merge is not by using `git merge`, at least not literally, as there is no way to handle conflicts.  GitHub won't even offer to make `M` if there would be merge conflicts.  But the effect is *as if* GitHub ran a literal `git merge`, so you can use this as a mental model, at least.

---

#### The simplest case: A=O, potential for fast-forward

Suppose the graph really does look like this:

```
...--D--E--F--A   <-- B
               \
                G--C   <-- (pull requested at C)
```

so that the *current* value of *`B`* is the same as the *old* value of *`B`* at the time the person making the pull-request made it.  That is, we have *`A`* = *`O`*.  If you use the default "merge" button on GitHub, you will get this:

```
...--D--E--F--A------M   <-- B
               \    /
                G--C
```

but the *contents* of commit `M` will match the *contents* of commit `C` exactly, which helps in several ways.

If you use the *rebase and merge* mode of the merge button, you get this:

```
...--D--E--F--A--G'-C'   <-- B
```

where the `G'` and `C'` commits are *copies* of the pull-requester's `G` and `C` commits: the snapshots match, and even the parent commit ID of `G'` matches that of `G`; what's different is the hash IDs: GitHub has made copies of both `G` and `C` even though there's no point to making such copies.  (I, for one, wish GitHub did not make these copies at all.  It's possible that other services don't.)  The original commits don't go in; the copies go in, instead.

If you use the *squash and merge* button, you get this:

```
...--D--E--F--A--S   <-- B
```

where the *parent* of `S` is `A`, while the *content* of `S` matches that of `C` exactly.  Again, commits `G` and `C` themselves does not enter the repository: only `C`'s content goes in (as the new snapshot in "squash" commit `S`).

#### Defining what you want

Now you know that the pull request is really a request to *move* the branch name, from where it is now (`A`) to something derived from the commit they've requested (`C`), perhaps by adding a new merge commit `M`, perhaps by adding a new squash-merge (ordinary single-parent non-merge commit) `S`, or perhaps by copying some or all of their commits.

What will actually happen, should you accept their pull request, depends on the button you click on GitHub, or if you're using something else (Bitbucket? GitLab? whatever it may be), whatever that system provides.  It's up to you to figure out what will *actually* happen.

Then, knowing what will actually happen, it's up to you yet again to figure out how to compare the commits that *will* go into your repository—commits that may not actually exist yet!—to the commits that already *are* in your repository.  Do you want to compare the contents of `C` to those of `A`?  Do you want to compare `C` to the contents of `O`, assuming the hash ID of `O` is available?  Or do you want to look carefully at what *each* new commit would do compared to its parent(s), even if none of those commits actually exist yet?

The last is, obviously, the hardest: but the production of these new commits follows a well-defined process, so to find out what they will contain, once they do exist, you can simply create them yourself, in your own repository, in the same way your web service will create them tomorrow, should you accept the pull request.  The caveat here is that if you *do* do this—if you project what they will do tomorrow—and then agree that you will click the button tomorrow, what happens if, tomorrow, branch `B` points to some commit other than `A`?

If you do choose this last option, of accepting based on what *would* happen, you will need to build some sort of process around the whole operation to make sure that what *would* happen remains the same as what *does* happen.  There are many ways to achieve that as well, none of which are perfect.

#### Achieving what you want

Once you have *defined* what you want, you still have to *achieve* it.  This is relatively straightforward for GitHub.  (I'm not sure what you would do for Bitbucket or other systems.)  You will start by using `git fetch` to obtain, into your own clone of your repository, copies of commit `C` and any parent commits it has that you lack.

Let's assume that `origin` is the name of the GitHub repository, and that the pull request is #123.  Then:

```
git fetch origin   # update everything so that we have origin/B pointing to A, etc
git fetch origin refs/pull/123/head:refs/heads/pr123
```

You now have a branch named `pr123` whose tip commit is commit `C`, along with your remote-tracking name `origin/B` pointing to commit `A`.

It's now easy to tell whether `A` is an ancestor of `C`, i.e., whether the simplest case is in effect.  This particular test is done this way in bash (not sure about PowerShell):

```
if git merge-base --is-ancestor refs/remotes/origin/B refs/heads/pr123; then
    echo "it's the simple case, yay"
else
    echo "it's the merge case, boo"
fi
```

In the simple case, regardless of which method you use to accept the pull request, the contents of final commit to which `origin/B` points in the end will match the contents of commit `C`, as pointed-to right now by `refs/heads/pr123`.<sup>2</sup>  If you've decided that the *change you want to test* is the *overall summary change*—that is, from `A` to `C`, without looking at any intermediate commits—then the files that will be modified are those listed by:

```
git diff-tree -r --name-status [options] refs/remotes/origin/B refs/heads/pr123
```

But if you wish to inspect intermediate commits as well, you have more work to do.

If you're in a *merge* case, things become even more complex, since—even if you're just going to compare the end-result to a single commit—you must now decide whether to compare to commit `A`, `O`, or something else entirely, such as the actual current merge base of `A` and `C`, whatever commit that may be.

If you *do* want to use the actual merge base, this is where the three-dot syntax can be useful.  However, due to minor bugs in older versions of Git, I'd advise running `git merge-base --all refs/heads/B refs/heads/pr123` here and collecting its output.  This will list some number of hash IDs, ideally just one: if you get just one, that's the merge base commit.  If you get more than one, they are *all* candidate merge bases, and the default `git merge -s recursive` strategy would first merge all the merge bases, then use the resulting commit as the merge base for the merges.

(It's often wisest, or at least simplest, to just reject complicated pull requests, telling whoever authored them that *they* must rework their pull request such that it does not require any special / fancy merging.)

---

<sup>2</sup>Typically, if you have remote-tracking name `origin/B` and branch-name `pr123` pointing to the desired commits, you *can* just use those names.  However, the method that Git uses to turn a name into a hash ID is a six-step process, outlined in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), and "use as branch name" is way down at step *four*, after "use as tag name"; "use as remote-tracking" name is step *five*.  What this means in practice is that if you have both *branch* `pr123` and *tag* `pr123`, the name `pr123` refers to the tag, rather than the branch.  For scripts, which will run with no human monitoring warning messages, it's wise to spell out the full names: `refs/remotes/origin/B` and `refs/heads/pr123`.  You can even resolve them once, to hash IDs, and then use the hash IDs everywhere, since the hash IDs never change.

Comment: Thank you for this. It really helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `...` instead of `..`

Comment: Does not seem this way.